# How to do select statement after THEN of SELECT CASE in SQL query?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to write query which has select statement after THEN of SELECT CASE in SQL query?
Example of logic

```
SELECT Id, CASE WHEN level=2 THEN 
    (select something here)
    else 0 end as Grade FROM CLASS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare the second select as a variable.

For example:

```
DECLARE @var as int
SET @var = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) 

SELECT
Id, 
CASE WHEN level=2 THEN @var else 0 end as Grade 
FROM CLASS
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the PHP Documentation you could run something along these lines:

Start by creating your database connection:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

This `if` statement is checking for the table `test` if it does not exists then drop it ***OR*** create the table `test` with the field `id` which is an `INT`

```
if (!$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test") || !$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE test(id INT)")) {
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Then if the conditions are try you run your queries here; here they have three queries.

**First** - counts the total rows in the table (which will equal 0)

**Second** - add a value to the table

**Third** - count the total rows again, which this time will output "1"

```
// this is what you may be asking?
// they add to their sql query
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS _num FROM test; ";
$sql.= "INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1); ";
$sql.= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS _num FROM test; ";
```

Make sure that the queries have been built correctly

```
if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Then run the code

```
do {
    if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)); // this will gather all records from the Database
        $res->free();
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result()); // You can find the links for documentation for more_results() and next_result() below
?>
```

**Documentation for [more_results()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.more-results.php) and [next_results()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php)**

Note the `$sql` as you can see they just create multiple queries that will run together if everything is true.

It will output this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["_num"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["_num"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

**Please note, this is not my code, I got it from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)**

Comment: Can you please guide me in SQL query?

Comment: There you go, I kind of broke down the steps... Again, this is not my code, give credit to the (owner)[http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php] And don't forget to read the documentation. It will help

Comment: You can also break down the queries in an ```if/else``` statement using PHP as long as the results are true, based on the query you are wanting to run...